# Array is just printing out last element

Tags: java, arrays

I am having this error where it prints out just the last element entered, prints out it the same amount of times as there are elements that are supposed to be in the array.

I have tested it with a `System.out.println` and the elements that are being added appear to be correct. How do I fix this error?

```
package stock.control.system;

import java.util.*;

public class StockArrayList implements StockList {

    private ArrayList<StockItem> StockItems;
    private int index = 0;
    private int update;
    private int counter = 0;

    public StockArrayList() {
        StockItems = new ArrayList<StockItem>(counter);
    }

    @Override
    public void addItem(StockItem item) {
        StockItem aItem = new StockItem(StockItem.getItemID(),
                                        StockItem.getItemDesc(),
                                        StockItem.getPrice(),     
                                        StockItem.getQuantity(), 
                                        StockItem.getReOrderLevel());

        StockItems.add(counter, aItem);
        counter++;
    }  

    @Override
    public String formatStockList(){

         String temp = StockItem.format();

         for (StockItem items : StockItems) {
              temp = temp + items.arrayFormat() + "\n";
         }   
         return temp;
   }
}
```

The main method:

```
public class StockArrayListTester {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        StockArrayList Stock = new StockArrayList();
        Stock.addItem(new StockItem("P123","1TB Hard drive",75.00,267,50));
        Stock.addItem(new StockItem("P125","i7 6800HQ Processor",257.00,113,45));
        Stock.addItem(new StockItem("P129","i5 500HQ Processor",127.00,10,45));
        Stock.deleteItem("P129");
        System.out.printf(Stock.formatStockList());

   }

}
```

the stock item class

```
package stock.control.system;

import java.util.*;

public class StockItem {
    private static String itemID; // Five alpha-numeric characters
    private static String itemDesc; // Item description
    private static double price; // Item price in pounds sterling
    private static int quantity; // Quantity in stock
    private static int reOrderLevel; // Level at which to re-order

    public StockItem(String itemID, String itemDesc, double price, int quantity, int reOrderLevel) {
        this.itemID = itemID;
        this.itemDesc = itemDesc;
        this.price = price;
        this.quantity = quantity;
        this.reOrderLevel = reOrderLevel;
   }

   @Override
   public String toString() {
       String toString ="[Item ID = " + this.itemID + ", Item Description = " +
               this.itemDesc + ", Price = " + this.price + ", Quantity = " + 
               this.quantity + ", Re Order Level = " + this.reOrderLevel + "]";

       return toString;
   }

   public static String format() {
       String format = "                                STOCK ITEMS" 
                + String.format("\n%-10s%-30s%-10s%-12s%-14s%-10s%-30s%-10s%-12s%-14s\n",
                    "ItemID","Item Description",
                    "Price","Quantity", "Re Order Level", "\n******",
                    " ****************"," *****", " ********",
                    " **************");
       return format;
   }

   public String arrayFormat() {
       return String.format("%-10s%-30s%-10s%-12s%-14s", 
                              StockItem.getItemID(),
                              StockItem.getItemDesc(),
                              StockItem.getPrice(),
                              StockItem.getQuantity(), 
                              StockItem.getReOrderLevel());
   }

   public static String getItemID(){
       return itemID;
   }

   public static String getItemDesc() {
       return itemDesc;
   }

   public static double getPrice() {
       return price;
   }

   public double setPrice(double price) {
       this.price = price;
       return price;
   }

   public static int getQuantity() {
       return quantity;
   }

   public int setQuantity(int quantity) {
       this.quantity = quantity;
       return quantity;
   }

   public static int getReOrderLevel(){
       return reOrderLevel;
   }

   public int setReOrderLevel(int reOrderLevel){
       this.reOrderLevel = reOrderLevel;
       return reOrderLevel;
   }   
}
```

The output I get is:

```
STOCK ITEMS
ItemID    Item Description              Price     Quantity    Re Order
P129      i5 500HQ Processor            127.0     10          45            
P129      i5 500HQ Processor            127.0     10          45            
P129      i5 500HQ Processor            127.0     10          45            
BUILD SUCCESSFUL (total time: 0 seconds)
```

Comment: And what is the `format` method? And, the `arrayFormat` method?

Comment: you create a new `StockItem` in your add method, but you somehow use `StockItem.getXXX`, but the parameter is called `item`. It seems as you are accessing some static methods, or the getter are even declared static.

Comment: format method and array format just format the output array format formats the string and format provides the headers

Comment: i have used get because i have tried using item in their place but it gives me an error says they are not the same length

Comment: Like @KevinEsche, I think that part of the problem lies in your StockItem class, can you edit your answer and show us its code?

Comment: My guess would be that all those attributes, `id`, `description`, `price`, `quantity` etc. are all `static`.

Comment: can we see the stock item class?

Comment: i have added the stock item class

Comment: Remove all that static, use item in addItem and you should be on the road

Comment: Thank you guys i have fixed the error i was because my variables were static. Thank you RC.

Comment: Now do some research what `static` means, so you will understand why this was absolutely wrong here.

Answer (score 3):

As a rule, never set `static` fields in a constructor. It is almost certainly a bug. IMHO, this should be a compiler error but it's not.

In this case, you are expecting each instance of `StockItem` to be different, however by making the fields `static` you are ensuring there is only one copy, only one value for those fields.  I suggest you make them instance fields.

```
public class StockItem {
    private final String itemID; // Five alpha-numeric characters
    private final String itemDesc; // Item description
    private double price; // Item price in pounds sterling
    private int quantity; // Quantity in stock
    private int reOrderLevel; // Level at which to re-order

    public StockItem(String itemID, String itemDesc, double price, int quantity, int reOrderLevel) {
        this.itemID = itemID;
        this.itemDesc = itemDesc;
        this.price = price;
        this.quantity = quantity;
        this.reOrderLevel = reOrderLevel;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

It's been a little while since I've used Java but it seems weird that in your addItem() method in your StockList class that you pass in a parameter 'item' but then never use it inside the method.

Why are you trying to "get" all of the properties of the stock item to add when you are passing them in to the function as a StockItem object?

Answer (score 0):

Guess something is wrong here:

```
@Override
public void addItem(StockItem item) {
StockItem aItem = new StockItem(StockItem.getItemID(),
        StockItem.getItemDesc(), StockItem.getPrice(), StockItem.getQuantity(), StockItem.getReOrderLevel());

StockItems.add(counter, aItem);
counter++;
}
```

All those getters are static methods. It does not make sense to me since I would think you want to get instance variables belonging to different objects. You must have initialiazed the StockItem class instance variables with the values printed out, otherwise I do not think your code would even compile.

Anyway why not adding the item passed as a parameter directly to the stock list?
Like so:

```
@Override
public void addItem(StockItem item) {

StockItems.add(counter, item);
counter++;
}
```